# Creating new column with list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a given dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon
I need to create new column based on another column called 'Name of the Pokemon'(string type) that will contain list of strings instead of strings

I need to use function. That's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')

def transform_faves(df):
    df = df.assign(name_as_list = df.name)  #new column
    list_of_a_single_column = df['name'].tolist()  
    df['name_as_list'] = list_of_a_single_column
    print(type(list_of_a_single_column))
    return df

df = transform_faves(df)
```

The problem is that new column is still string rather than list of strings. Why such conversion does not work?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Ideally provide a small input example and the matching expected output.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to add a list of all names at each row in the df? Eg `df['name_as_list'] = [df['Name of the Pokemon'].tolist()] * len(df)`?